# Rails can't include AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, angularjs

I'm following this [tutorial](http://rubydoc.info/gems/angularjs-rails/1.0.1.1/frames) and although adding it to the Gem file and bundle installing it works fine. The moment I try to include it into application.js, the file, I get the following error while loading it:

```
throw Error("Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'angular'\n  (in /my/path/to/rails/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13)")
```

application.js file looks like so (starting with line 13):

```
//= require angular
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
//= require bootstrap
//= require pusher.min.js
//= require pusher_setup
//= require_directory .
```

Therefore, my question is how can I successfully include AngularJS into my Rails project?

I'm currently using Rails 3.2.2, and Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had face same problem. I resolved it by following way.

1) In my case, `//= require_tree .` was missing in `application.js` file.. so i have added it.

2) Restarted Apache Server (If webrick, then restart it)

Comment: I'm still investigating what happened, however, by the looks of things, once that line is added to application.js for a while, it can be removed. It sounds weird, and I'm still investigating what changed to allow it to work without require_tree.

Comment: require_tree . will result in you having a single file (application.js in this case) holding all your scripts that is there in the folder.

Answer (score 5):

After adding a gem you always have to restart the web server.

From looking at the gem's source code, it has the angular javascripts in `vendor/assets/javascripts`, which means they will be available by just doing `//= require angular`. If they don't load, it's probably because the server needs to be restarted and you need to bundle install.

As for the `require_tree .`, I strongly advise against that, because it means you will lose control over the order in which things get loaded.

For example angular itself is packaged with it's own version of jQuery (jQuery-lite), but if there is already jQuery present when it is loaded, it will use the *global* version.

Which means doing

```
//= reqiure angular 
//= require jquery
```

will do something different, than

```
//= require jquery
//= require angular
```

There are many other cases when load order can matter, for example if you have Backbone.js and Underscore, you will want to load Underscore before Backbone, etc.

As a general practice I would always recommend just using `require`, unless you're loading your own code where order doesn't matter, for example `//= require_tree ./controllers` for your own directory of controllers. In that case I'd say `require_tree` is perfectly ok.

Comment: It's weird because there's nothing in vendor/assets/javascripts other than one hidden file. Is that meant to be normal after having added it to the Gem file, bundle installed, and restarted foreman?

Comment: @Hengjie it won't copy in your rails application direclty. The gem itself has a `vendor/assets/javascripts` directory with the file.

Answer (score 4):

in your gemfile if you are using like this :

```
group :assets  do
   gem 'angularjs-rails'
end
```

then remove that group :assets thing, It should be simple without block:

ex:

```
gem 'angularjs-rails'
```

It will definitely work

Comment: In rails 4 version, May be there is some conflict with assets for this gem, need to check

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone had a same issue and the offered solution wouldn't work.
I have added `//= require angular` in the asset

```
group :assets do
//= require angular
end
```

However still I was getting the same error. After a bit of search I found out that for some reason it needs to be **added outside of the assets group**. All good now. Not sure if this is a best way though however I am not getting this error anymore.